# Date difference in shell script

Tags: shell, date

I am new to shell scripting. I am trying to add 5 years to a date 2021-04-12T15:00:42.222+00:00.
I have seen few example in simple YYYY-mm-dd format but nothing for the above one. Please help

Comment: Edit your Q to show your best attempt to solve your problem. Include the required output. AND the output you are currently getting. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works in Ubuntu 20:10. Should work on most (if not all) distros:

```
date -d "2021-04-12T15:00:42.222+00:00 +5 years"
```

Comment: didnt work i got this message usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

Comment: What distro are you running? what is the output of
date --version
?